# How to update value in User Table in laravel 5.1

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.1

I have an issue I cannot update my user table . I don't know where he problem is.Whenever I submit my updated info it cannot updated. It Does not show any error. But the table is not updated. Please Help me guys.
My Controller is

```
public function getUpdate() {

        $profile = Auth::user();
        return view('admin.article.edit')
        ->with('profile',$profile);
    }

    public function postUpdate(Request $request ) {
$profile = Auth::user();

        $this->validate($request, [
            'name' => 'required|max:120',
            'username' => 'required|max:80',
            'email' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required'
            ]);

         // save users table
        $profile = Auth::user();
        // $user = new App\User;
        $profile->name = $request->input('name');
        $profile->email = $request->input('email');
        $profile->username = $request->input('username');
        $profile->password = $request->input('password');
        $profile->update();
}
```

My edit.blade.php page is

```
<?php $active="profile"; ?>
@extends('admin.dashboard')
@section('content')
  <!-- Content Wrapper. Contains page content -->
  <div class="content-wrapper">
    <!-- Content Header (Page header) -->
    <section class="content-header">
      <h1>
        User Profile
      </h1>
      <ol class="breadcrumb">
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> Home</a></li>
        <li class="active">User profile</li>
      </ol>
    </section>

<!-- Main content -->
    <section class="content">
      <div class="row">
        <!-- left column -->
        <div class="col-md-10">
          <!-- general form elements -->
          <div class="box box-primary">
            <div class="box-header with-border">
              <h3 class="box-title">Quick Example</h3>
            </div>
            <!-- /.box-header -->
            <!-- form start -->
            <form action="{{ route('update') }}" role="form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
              <div class="box-body">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="name">Name</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" {{ $errors->has('name') ? 'class=has-error' : '' }} value="{{ Request::old('name') ? Request::old('name') : isset($profile) ? $profile->name : '' }}">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="username">User Name</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="institute" id="institute" {{ $errors->has('username') ? 'class=has-error' : '' }} value="{{ Request::old('institute') ? Request::old('username') : isset($profile) ? $profile->institute : '' }}">
                </div>
</div>
              <!-- /.box-body -->

              <div class="box-footer">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ Session::token() }}">
                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ $profile->id }}">
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
          <!-- /.box -->

        </div>
        <!--/.col (left) -->
      </div>
      <!-- /.row -->
    </section>
    <!-- /.content -->
@endsection
```

My route file is

```
Route::get('/profile/edit', [
                    'uses' => 'ProfileController@getUpdate',
                    'as' => 'edit'
            ]);

        Route::post('profile/update', [
                    'uses' => 'ProfileController@postUpdate',
                    'as' => 'update'
            ]);
```

Comment: in your postUpdate i see $profile = Auth::user(); two times why?

Comment: To get my user info and update it i use $profile = Auth::user(); two times. @Iftikhar uddin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your route you should write this

```
Route::get('/profile/{profile_id}/edit', [
                    'uses' => 'ProfileController@getUpdate',
                    'as' => 'edit'
            ]);

        Route::post('profile/update', [
                    'uses' => 'ProfileController@postUpdate',
                    'as' => 'update'
            ]);
```

And in your controller you should write this

```
public function getUpdate() {
        $divisions = Division::all();
        $districts = District::all();
        $dcategories = Dcategory::all();
        $profile = Auth::user();

        return view('admin.article.edit')
        ->with('divisions',$divisions)
        ->with('districts',$districts)
        ->with('dcategories',$dcategories)
        ->with('profile',$profile);
    }

    public function postUpdate(Request $request ) {

        $this->validate($request, [
            'name' => 'required|max:120',
            'fee' => 'required|max:5',
            'division_id' => '',
            'district_id' => '',
            'dcategory_id' => '',
            'education' => '',
            'institute' => '',
            'specialty' => '',
            'hospital' => '',
            'time' => '',
            'phone' => '',
            'image' =>''            
            ]);


        $doctor = Auth::user();
        $doctor->name = $request['name'];
        $doctor->division_id = $request['division_id'];
        $doctor->district_id = $request['district_id'];
        $doctor->dcategory_id = $request['dcategory_id'];
        $doctor->institute = $request['institute'];
        $doctor->education = $request['education'];
        $doctor->specialty = $request['specialty'];
        $doctor->hospital = $request['hospital'];
        $doctor->phone = $request['phone'];
        $doctor->time = $request['time'];
        $doctor->fee = $request['fee'];

        // $photo = Photo::find($request['id']);
        $logo=$request->file('image');
        if(!empty($logo)) {
            $upload='uploads/logo';
            $filename=$logo->getClientOriginalName();
            $success=$logo->move($upload,$filename);

            $doctor->image = $filename;
        }
```

This might solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try This

First check you have made fillable all fields you are updating.

App/Entites/User.php

```
<?php
protected $fillable = ['name', 'email', 'password','username'];
```

and then update records

```
$profile = Auth::user();
$profile->name = $request->name;
$profile->email = $request->email;
$profile->username = $request->institute;
$profile->password = bcrypt($request->password);
$profile->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$profile = Auth::user();
```

creates a new row and `$profile->save();` will save the records.

to update the specific row specify that row.e.g.

```
    $id=$request->input('id');

    $profile = User::where(['id'=>$id])->first();
    $profile->name = $request->input('name');
    $profile->email = $request->input('email');
    $profile->username = $request->input('username');
    $profile->password = $request->input('password');
    $profile->update();
```

Comment: Did not work. Still it did not updated the record. @Sanzeeb Aryal

Comment: No it did not gave me any error but it did not update my info  @Sanzeeb Aryal

Answer (score 0):

It is not updating because in your Form view there is no username you have institute in the name attribute

```
name="institute"
```

Change that to username and try. PLUS you don't have fields for password and email.

Comment: Did you changed name field to username ?

Comment: `$profile->username = $request->input('username');` this gonna grab the user from request which has name = 'username' and you have name = 'institute' it won't work that way.

Comment: I change name='institute' to name='username'. But it did not work either

Comment: ok once you change that to username now do change the ->update to ->save and try!

Comment: Your form has errors remove that and it will work for sure.

Comment: Check my Code for update https://github.com/iftikharuddin/pos/blob/master/resources/views/user/update.blade.php BUT note i am using Resource Controller for it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you get user from auth(). So change

```
$profile = Auth::user();
$profile->name = $request->input('name');
$profile->email = $request->input('email');
$profile->username = $request->input('username');
$profile->password = $request->input('password');
$profile->update();
```

To

```
$profile = Auth::user();
$profile->name = $request->input('name');
$profile->email = $request->input('email');
$profile->username = $request->input('username');
// Hash
$profile->password = \Hash::make($request->input('password'));
// Change to save method
$profile->save();
```

Try it!

Comment: No it did not work @KmasterYC.Still it did not update the user info

Comment: I see there has problems with validate. It does not match form request. Remove or change validate and test again

Comment: Would you please tell me what is the updated code for my validate @KmasterYC

Comment: Plz check the form. It has only 2 variables but in controller you validate 4 variables

Comment: I remove the othe 2 variables from my controller but still it did not work @KmasterYC

Answer (score 0):

```
//this will load the currently logged in user
$profile = auth()->user();

//if your user db have column 'name' and you wanna update it
$profile->name = 'Jezzabelle';

//save to the db
$profile->save();
```